# What's the most efficient way of creating dynamic page body?

Tags: php, html, database, file

I've took a look at the PHP script behind my father website which has been built by a hired programmer. Now, I'm not thinking that I'm better than him, but I think its technique might not be the best.

The website has dynamic page body, in the meaning that my dad can, via a specific admin page, modify the HTML content of most of the webpages in the website. Right now it's made via database: the pages are all stored in the database and every request deals with a query that fetches the page from the database and implement it.

Now, I think this way is very bad mostly because it requires (even if not that expensive if cached) an additional query to the database. 
Wouldn't it be more efficient to store the pages as HTML files and then just modify the file itself when required? In this way the editing of the file, I think, is faster, and the loading of the content of an html file per request is a lot easier and faster than perform a query.

Is it? Is there any other (more efficient) way to handling this situation?

Comment: Seeing that your dad probably doesn't update his page as often as the page will be requested. Your proposed implementation will be more resource optimal. However only a comparison of both implementations will show the difference in performance and thus best-method in this case.

Question is, do you want to spend time to change code in order to validate a performance gain without knowing up front that there will be one :)

Comment: It's a fun question, but imho it's not quite a practical (SO-type) question solliciting a real, definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several good reasons why a CMS should use a Database to store/fetch the dynamic content. Just as there are several reasons why you might prefer not to rely on a DB.

- Pro Db:

  - *Security*: It's an obvious, and slightly ambivalent argument, but nonetheless. If you decide to store your content as separate files on your server, they'll need to be stored in a directory that doesn't allow public access. If not, users might be able to access the chunks of your site separatly, which comes across as unprofessional. 
    People with ignoble intentions will have an easy time altering your site's content, too. Of course, there are many ways to prevent this, and increase overall security. Database systems, when left to their own devices, aren't exactly safe either, but provide an extra obstacle to hackers with minimal effort.
    *note:* The security argument stands, or falls with how well your script filters out injection, and how secure you set up your server.
  - Disk usage. When using separate files to compose each requested page, The server has to access its HD on each request. Again, caching solves this issue to some extend, but it's easier and (in general) better to cache DB query results (performance wise). Either on your Database server, in PHP, or, better still, both.
  - Logging. By this I mean: when you alter the content, a database driven CMS is a lot easier to manage. If you altered the content, and want to undo/rollback the changes, a DB is the easiest way to implement such a feature. Using HTML, you'll soon find yourself wading through tons of files called `site_menu_block_YYYY-mm-dd.html.backup`. Even if this is done by a script, it'll almost certainly be slower than using a DB.
  - Translation: as vlzvl pointed out, if you're using static pages, you'll either end up with each page N times, once for each language. When altering the stylesheets, you'll then have to alter N files, too. Which is resource expensive. Alternatively, your scripts will parse an HTML template file for each request, and an XML file with the actual contents. This way you loose the SEO benefit of the HTML files, *and* cause extra server load **and** slow down your site.
- Pro HTML:

  - I can only give 1 solid pro argument here: it's a lot easier to get an SEO site this way. Just allow search engines to index the separate files. This does decrease the overall security of your CMS **drastically** .

That said, I think I'm right in saying that all major CMS's use both methods, depending on what type of data they're dealing with. HTML headers, for example, are often partially stored as separate files, just like JS files and style-sheets.

Comment: Consider also that a query per request is heavier than a `file_get_content()` execution.

Comment: In general, you're right. But a query can be cached and buffered a lot better/easier than a file. Databases can be protected in more ways, too. If you want your files to be protected, good chance you'll end up `chmod`-ing the files, getting their contents, and `chmod`-ing them again. That's 3 operations, not 1. It's that kind of overhead you have to take into consideration, too.

Comment: BTW: as soon as you start `chmod`-ing, your host user will need certain user rights, which is a huge security issue

Answer (score 2):

this is the question of the century :) there is no exact answer to this question. just performance tips. people are working to optimize page load times during recent 30 years.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, he's perfectly right. It's really just a matter of opinion....

Answer (score 2):

No it isnt better to have fixed HTML pages under an hypothetical **'/mypages'** folder.

- What if the user wants **about 500 contents** in his webpage? he'll end up with 500 files.
- Yeah sure, they'll be served faster but is that enough against the massive problems below?
- What about **page translation**? this would be nightmare in static html files.
- Pages are rendered that way because they're dynamic; that is, **stuff can be "entered" by third parties/plugins (say)** and applied into multiple contents at once; what about applying the same stuff into numerous **HTMLs** and then changing it **again**?
- What about if you want to change the **< HEAD>**er and **< SCRIPT>**s loaded? you'll be forced to do that in all 500 contents** in every change.
- What about the **PHP** included in those **.html** files? This is not a reason if you're not putting PHP into this but in case of an included php file renamed/removed you'll need to change all files in a massive update.
- Think of **templates**; the reason the modern **CMS** (or admin pages) are dynamic today is because they can change classes/styles etc. without affecting content itself. A single change to theme used or a single class would cause (again) a massive update.
- Database is **files** too, but run **faster**. If you worry about performance you can program the database to use caching (queries like **SELECT data FROM content WHERE id=1**) so the query is almost no-query in performance terms.

I can think of more.

Comment: Translation... I forgot about that one :P

Comment: can be a pain; this would result of either N*langs supported static files or php involved; both will be bad in static htmls in my opinion..

Comment: I couldn't agree more, hence the +1. I live and work as a developer in a country with 3 official languages, so translation something I deal with on a daily basis. Hence nobody here would even consider using static HTML blocks. All sites here support at least 2 languages, most support 4 ~ 5 languages. Imagine the horror if you were to use static pages

Comment: Wait, maybe I didn't explained it clear: The page body is stored in the database, not the page itself. This means that in the database there is only text and nothing else (a part from some <b> and <i> somewhere for text formatting).

Comment: Also there isn't any need of translation in that particular website.

Comment: I was assuming the page wasn't fully stored in a DB. If it was, your father would have been ripped off! Still, check my answer, even if you're not storing html in your db, there are many, many reasons not to use HTML files. keeping a change log of the site's content, for example

Comment: I see. This is the normal way, but i think the problems are same in this approach too (storing page body only in files and serving these). You'll need to include() them in the final page anyway. What about the future? about translations i mean. What about a single php operation that has to be included in every static html instead of automatic do-it by the admin in specific position? This is ok for small sites, but as something grows the requirements are changing and the rewrite could be nightmare.

Comment: @vlzvl amen to that. @Jeffrey: You might think this doesn't apply to your case. But believe me when I say: it might very well not apply __yet__. You've heard the term `scalability` so many times, for a reason. Your model won't scale - full stop. Not _won't scale well_, it doesn't scale. The DB driven CMS's scale a lot better

Comment: You don't make a very good point. a simple CMS would solve all those problems.

Comment: What this assumption has to do with the question or my post? huh? my point is to go against plain file-based html serving.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the content. When you have much different content, like news it's easier to store the data inside a database for each newsentry and load the data into a template. But when you have single content (like a huge article or info page) you can use a HTML to store the data.

It also depends on if you want a multi-language page or not. You can surly create a multi-linugal page with only HTMLs. But here's the same as above. What content do you have. Much different entries or less same content?

But, what I have done so far was I did both at the same time: When a client wanted a page with news script and multi-language and so on I created the page that the user can log in for news entries and store the news in different languages, but changes to other sites are made via HTML and there was for every language a different html file.

EDIT:

It depends on the user, too. If the user don't know how to use HTML but wants to change the site hisself than the only available option is the option to give him an admin center to make changes. OR if you don't want give to much power to the user :D

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: Most CMS handle lots of DB accesses and load many files in order to compile one page that is eventually sent to a visitor. Still, for most sites there's no performance problem (i.e. most pages loading in < 1s). So I'd be surprised if you have a problem there, with just one single DB access. 
But for handling, why use a database, when your site doesn't really need it? 
I made a couple of sites for clients where I use one index.php that loads one menu file and one footer file that are the same for all pages, and inbetween it loads the individual selected html files. So in order to edit a page, you use any editor to open and edit the corresponding html. Very simple.

Comment: Just to clarify: I generally prefer CMS. But for very simple sites, few pages, no login etc., I do it this way, because for me it's the simplest and fastest (i.e. for the client the cheapest) way to "develop" a site.

Comment: Obliviously even with 20 queries the user browsing the website will not see any difference. It's not about "how much time does it take" it's about "what's the best choice".